# image in table not centered properly

Tags: html, css

I have a table class that is normally centered, but when I put an img tag inside it it does not center properly, it aligns everything left. I have tried many css things from google to no avail. Please help. Here is the code:

```
<table class="invisible" style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <form id="event" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/en/events/add/submit">
        <tr><td>Event Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>" required></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Date: </td><td><input type="text" id="date" name="date" required></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Start Time: </td><td><input type="text" name="startTime" value="<?php echo $startTime ?>" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' required></td></tr>
        <tr><td>End Time: </td><td><input type="text" name="endTime" value="<?php echo $endTime ?>" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' required></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Description: </td><td><br><textarea name="description" id="description" required><?php echo $description ?></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Image: </td><td><img src="/<?php echo $banner ?>" alt="image" style="max-width:25%;></td></tr>
        <tr><td>New Image: </td><td><input type="file" name="file" id="file"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><br><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="verifyData()"></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.invisible
{
     margin: 0 auto;
}
table.invisible td
{
     border: 0;
}
```

Comment: You put a `<form>` inside a `<table>`?

Comment: You would need a width and `margin:0  auto;` on the image, not the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put a width:50% on the invisible table and max-width:100% on the image and it seems to work

Comment: That doesn't align the table center.

Comment: I have updated my original anwer. This is a correct and proper solution to align all your table and images to the center.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a solution, but you're missing a closing double quotes in the style property on this line:

```
<tr><td>Image: </td><td><img src="/<?php echo $banner ?>" alt="image" style="max-width:25%;></td></tr>
```

Comment: thanks for letting me know, but no it does not solve the problem

Comment: @IVAOCA-WM I'm pretty sure I've solved the problem for you. You can try to add the margin as I explain above and try the center-alignment again. I linked a pic to how your site looks when you make that change.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to change is to add this to your css:

```
#mceu_5 {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Does not work, see comment on other answer for link to the live demo with text-align:center; It will work as a demo until it is fixed. Thanks

Comment: Did the demo 2 help? Did you try changing the margin on the input element?

Comment: i tried inline style for demo 1 and demo 2 but it does not work

Comment: However the table is aligned center if I dont include the img tag and it is also used on several other pages succesfully

Comment: I just noticed that the file upload for a new image doesnt show up either

Comment: The file upload doesn't show because of the missing `"` in your image that I mentioned.

Comment: the entire table should be centered.The tiny mce textarea is fine without the img tag and the table is also centered without it

Comment: @IVAOCA-WM I'm confused now. The link I provided above shows the entire table centered *with* the image. So can you not do this change?